# Does Azure App service communicate internally without going out through Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have Azure App Services behind the Azure Application Gateway/Firewall. There are few application that talks between them. Does that applications talk internally(using xxx.azurewebsites.net) or they talk with public domain(mydomain.com)?

Also, how to check these things in logs.

Current configuration:

*HTTPSettings:* Pick hostname from the backend address has checked.

*Probes:* pick hostname from backend https settings has checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, No if your applications are inside azure's network, it usually wont go through the public domain. But it will go through the firewall/gateways and follow the same networking restriction you have defined.

What logs you want to check? if you want to see the application event logs you can do it using scm. You can access it via Diagnostics/Advanced Tools in your azure app services.

Comment: The applications are Azure Web App Service Plan premium tier. Gateways/firewall has path-based rule to the backend pool. Gateway has pointed to public domain and we access the application from the public domain.  I want to check gateway logs where I can see the redirection has done using azurewebsites.net as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/application-gateway/troubleshoot-app-service-redirection-app-service-url

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Access Logs in the Application gateway to see all the request that hits Application Gateway. It has the hostname field where you can check how the site is being accessed.

Let me know if you have any further questions.